# Users can't see project files

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a project in TFS on Visual Studio Online. I added one user to this project, but he can't see any files in repository. He can see created tasks. I gave him administration privileges but he still cannot see any files. What may be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

He has not been assigned a licence for accessing code. It sounds like he is on the Stakeholder licence group.

If you click the VSO logo to right and then select the Users tab you can assign him to "basic" or above to get access to code.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you resolve this somehow? My user already has the access level Basic.